# ¿Cómo acceder a datos de un List sacado de JSON en C# y Unity?

Tags: c#, json, lista, unity

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio en el cual quiero pasar los datos de un JSON a unos InputFields de Unity.

A la hora de escribir la que entiendo que es la sintaxis correcta, me indica siempre que los Index están fuera de rango por lo que me es imposible acceder a la información leída.

El JSON:

```
{
  "personajes":[
      {"nombre":"Pepe","apellido":"Lereie","puntos":15},
      {"nombre":"David","apellido":"Garcia","puntos":99}
  ]
}
```

Clase Usuarios

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Usuarios
{
    public string nombre;
    public string apellido;
    public int puntos;

}
```

Clase Personajes

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Personajes 
{
   public List<Usuarios> personajes;

}
```

Script Controller de Unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField entradaNombre, entradaApellidos, entradaPuntos;
    string fichero;
    string datos;
    Personajes lista;

    void Awake()
    {

        fichero = Application.dataPath + "/Files/lista.json";
        datos = File.ReadAllText(fichero);
        lista = JsonUtility.FromJson<Personajes>(datos);

        entradaNombre.text = lista.personajes.ToArray()[0].nombre;
    }

}
```

Si en vez de utilizar

```
entradaNombre.text = lista.personajes.ToArray()[0].nombre;
```

Utilizo

```
entradaNombre.text = lista.personajes[0].nombre;
```

Obtengo el mismo error dentro de Unity

Comment: ¿Qué cantidad de elementos te dice que tiene `lista.personajes.Count`? ¿Estás seguro de que el archivo se está leyendo correctamente?

Comment: Al realizar  esa instruccion me indica que tengo 0 elementos. El fallo no creo que sea del datos = File.ReadAllText(fichero); sino del lista = JsonUtility.FromJson<Personajes>(datos); ya que la salida con Debug.log de datos es el json leido

Comment: Prueba colocar `{get;set;}` en todas las variables de tus clases `Usuarios` y `Personajes ` Ejemplo: `public List<Usuarios> personajes {get;set;}` Luego `public string nombre {get;set;}` y así con el resto